# HTML5 video tag not working with "codecs" attribute on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, codec

I´ve got a "video" tag as follows:

```
<video id="videoTag" loop autoplay controls preload poster="xxx.jpg" height="100%" width="100%">
      <source src="xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.64001E, mp4a.40.2'"/>
</video>
```

it has been working perfectly in Chrome until a recent Chrome update (can´t assure which version), since that update i had to remove the "codecs" attribute from "source", leaving something like this:

```
<video id="videoTag" loop autoplay controls preload poster="xxx.jpg" height="100%" width="100%">
      <source src="xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

and now it is working well.

My question is: why did it happen? Does Chrome no longer supports the "codecs" attribute or that codec specifically? Is the "codesc" attribute really useful for a browser?
Could you please shed some light on it?

BTW, it always has work well on IE11, with and withous "codecs" attribute.

Thanks!